# How to append updated data in previous state in react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i am creating a file system App using react-redux and am new to this.
i just want to append the latest data into previous data.

here is my code snippet

action.js

```
export function getFolderList(url){
const local_url_LOW = isLocal ? lowJSON : url + '?fileFidelity=LOW';
const  lowRequest = axios.get(local_url_LOW);
return{
    type: GET_FOLDER_LIST,
    payload: lowRequest
};
}
```

reducer.js

```
export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case GET_FOLDER_LIST:
        let data = action.payload.data.Files.File

        folderData = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data];
        if (folderData.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < folderData.length; i++) {
                lst.push({
                    id: folderData[i].oid,
                    name: folderData[i].location,
                    type: folderData[i].type,
                    childCount: folderData[i].childCount,
                    createdDate: folderData[i].createdDate,
                    lastModifiedDate: folderData[i].lastModifiedDate,
                    location: folderData[i].location

                });
            }
            return lst;
        }
        break;

}
return state;
}
```

so i want to return data like .. state.chlidFiles : lst
so can anyone tell me hoe to do this.
currently when my returning lst array it is creating new state with the previous and the lst arrya, but i want to add this new lst array in previous state's childFiles(or you can say to a specific property)

i have used redux-promise for promises.

Comment: Can you explain some little bit more information what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Also, what is your INITIAL_STATE? At the end you want something like state: { childFiles: lst }?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @ApurvG , now m returning  only selected list .. no need to append in the main array. 
i.e in selected list there is childFile property and i m appending data in this array and return the seledtedList .. .

Answer (score 0):

I am shooting a blind suggestion here. I would use redux-thunk for async operation, then I would dispatch this and use in my reducer.

**action**

```
const getFolderList = (url) =>
    ( dispatch) => {
        const local_url_LOW = isLocal ? lowJSON : url + '?fileFidelity=LOW';
        const lowRequest = await axios.get(local_url_LOW);
        const data = lowRequest.data.Files.File;
        const folderData = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data];
        const payload = folderData.map( file => ( {
                id: file.oid,
                name: file.location,
                type: file.type,
                childCount: file.childCount,
                createdDate: file.createdDate,
                lastModifiedDate: file.lastModifiedDate,
                location: file.location,
            } ) );

        dispatch(  {
            type: GET_FOLDER_LIST,
            payload,
        } )
    }
```

**reducer**

```
export default function ( state = INITIAL_STATE, action ) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
    case GET_FOLDER_LIST:
        return { ...state, childFiles: [ ...state.childFiles,  ...action.payload ] };
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: { ...state, childFiles: [ ...state.childFiles,  ...action.payload ] } this doesn't work

Comment: What is the error or problem? I don't know how exactly is state, so this is why i said blind suggestion. Also, do you have the same code as OP?